# Как реализовать перемещение линии внутри блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Чтобы при зажатии на линию двигать эту линию в пределах блока.

Потылся сделать сам, но что то пошло не так...

```js
let isMoveOrder = 0;

$(document).on('mousedown', '.line', function(e) {
  if (e.button == 0) {
    isMoveOrder = 1;
  }
}).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  isMoveOrder = 0;
});

$(document).on('mousemove', '.line', function(e) {
  if (isMoveOrder) $('.line').css('top', e.pageY +'px');
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  height: 10px;
  background: #090;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем подключать jQuery и не пользоваться её возможностями?

```js
$('.line').draggable({ axis: 'y', containment: 'parent' });
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100px; width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; left: 0;
  height: 10px; width: 100%;
  background: #090;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы были на правильном пути, но нужно учесть, что линия находиться внутри ограниченного блока и прописать проверки под это.

Так же, данная часть кода будет работать не корректно.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.line', function(e) {
  if (e.button == 0) {
    isMoveOrder = 1;
  }
}).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  isMoveOrder = 0;
});
```

Если зажать мышь при наведении на линию то `isMoveOrder = 1`, а если например отвести мышь в сторону и отпустить скрипт не заработает и `isMoveOrder` не будет равен `0`.

Лучше разделить нажатие и отпускание кнопки

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.line', function (e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
        isMoveOrder = 1;
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    isMoveOrder = 0;
});
```

**Вот рабочий код**

```js
let isMoveOrder = 0,
  contentPoistionTop = $('.content').offset().top, // Находим вверхнюю точку родительского блока по отношению к документу
  contentPoistionBottom = contentPoistionTop + $('.content').height(); // Находим нижнюю точку родительского блока по отношению к документу

$(document).on('mousedown', '.line', function(e) {
  if (e.button == 0) {
    isMoveOrder = 1;
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  isMoveOrder = 0;
});

$(document).on('mousemove', '.line', function(e) {
  if (isMoveOrder) {
    let newTopPosition = e.pageY - $('.line').height() / 2 - contentPoistionTop; // Вычисляем значение для перемещения ("Значение курсора" - "вверхняя точка род.блока" - "Половина высоты линии")  P.S. Пол. высоты линии нужна, чтобы центрировать курсор при передвижении? без него передвижение вверх не работает
    if (newTopPosition < 0) { // Из-за рассчета пол. высоты линии, линия вылазит за края, для этого делаем проверку
      newTopPosition = 0;
    } else if (newTopPosition > $('.content').height() - $('.line').height()) {
      newTopPosition = $('.content').height() - $('.line').height();
    }
    $('.line').css('top', newTopPosition + "px");
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 10px;
  background: #090;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```